# Missing argument 1 in laravel RESTful controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am moving my controllers from the defining get/post to a restful variety.  Though my Get method is working, I am running into a problem regarding missing arguments in my post method. Both were working when specifically naming get/post in my route.

Do you see the error I am making? TIA

The error I am getting is:

```
Missing argument 1 for ContractorController::postLogos()
```

Here is my route:

```
Route::controller('/contractors', 'ContractorController');
```

Here is my ContractorController:

```
public function getLogos($id)
    {

        //
        $contractor = Contractor::find($id);
        return View::make('contractors.logos')
            ->with('contractor', $contractor);
    }

public function postLogos($id){
  $contractor = Contractor::find($id);


  $input = Input::all();
  $rules = array(
      'file' => 'image|max:3000',
  );

  $validation = Validator::make($input, $rules);

  if ($validation->fails())
  {
    return Response::make($validation->errors->first(), 400);
  }
    $file = Input::file('file');
    $destinationPath = 'uploads/logos';
    //$filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
    $filename = str_random(12).".{$extension}";
    $upload_success = Input::file('file')->move($destinationPath, $filename);
    $path = Input::file('file')->getRealPath();

    if( $upload_success ) { 
        ##$contractor = Contractor::find($id);

        ##$logo = new Logo(array('name' => Input::file('file')->getRealPath()));
        ##$logo = $contractor->logo()->save($logo);

        $logo = new Logo;
        $logo->name = $destinationPath ."/". $filename;
        $logo->contractor_id = (Input::get('contractor_id'));
        $logo->save();
       return Response::json('success', 200);
    } else {
       return Response::json('error', 400);
    }
}
```

And my view:

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => array('ContractorController@postLogos'),'files' => true, $contractor->id)) }}

            <div class="span6 bdb bdb-larger">
                    <input type="file" class="filestyle" name="file" id="file" accept="image/*">
                    <script>$(":file").filestyle({classInput: "input-small"});</script>
                    <input type="hidden" name="contractor_id"  value="{{$contractor->id}}">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
        {{Form::close()}}

            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the problem.

The form can't call the method like it does in a post route, It has to call the view. So I changed it from:

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => array('ContractorController@postLogos'),'files' => true, $contractor->id)) }}
```

to:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'contractors/logos/{$id}','files' => true, $contractor->id)) }}
```

It works great now.